# Performing ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, parallel-processing

I need to increase the performance of a ForEach.

```
//Pseudocode
foreach (item i item in items)
{
//Call service to open DB conn and get data
}
```

Within this loop make a call to a service that opens a session sqlserver, gets data from the database and closes the session, so for each iteration.
What I can do?.
Thanks.

Comment: You could start by profiling the application to see if the looping is really the bottleneck.

Comment: Are you sure parallelization will help? Sounds to me like the bottleneck will occur on database IO, negating speedups by parallelization.

Comment: Yes, I sure need it, because I've tried with and without parallel loop and the difference is huge. The problem is that with the default options of Parallel takes me a lot.

Comment: So the relevant part of the question is "takes me a lot". Which is incomprehensible.

Comment: Excuse me but I´m no speak english and I use an automatic traductor

Comment: MGG_Soft: a good reason to use more C# in your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that does sound like a perfectly good use of [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) - so have you tried it?

```
Parallel.ForEach(queries, query => {
    // Perform query
});
```

You may well want to specify options around the level of parallelism etc - and make sure your connection pool supports as many connections as you want. And of course, *measure* the performance before and after to make sure it's actually helping.

Comment: Do you you mean the number of simultaneous threads?. How I can increase the level of parallelism?.

Comment: @MGG_Soft: See the linked documentation, and find overloads containing a `ParallelOptions` parameter.

Comment: great way! is this way effective for each itartion on lists in c#?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes - the answer was meant to be validating that Parallel.ForEach is indeed a good idea.

Comment: @RRR: Yes, it's fine for lists.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could start a new thread in each iteration:

```
foreach (item i in collection)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(functionToCall);
    t.Start()
}

functionToCall()
{
    database = openSQLSession();
    data databaseData = database.getData();
    dataCollection.Add(databaseData);
    closeSQLSession();
}
```

Of course this is a simple example and pretty pseudocode-y, but I hope you get the gist of it?

Comment: I'll remember but I do not improve